# fscanf to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I'm in trouble with my code again.
I want to `fscanf` result.txt to structures with linked list, but it don't work;
I think the simply linked list must be enought;

The problem is: the program just write the first line, but nothing else.

result.txt format:

```
point name (for examples)
623   john
457   peter
312   chuck
etc.
```

The code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct ranklist {
        int point;
        char* name;
        struct ranklist *next;
    } ranklist;

    int how_many_records(FILE *fp){
        char ch;
        int line=0;
        int status;

        rewind(fp);
        while((status=fscanf(fp, "%*d %*[^\n]%c", &ch))==1)
            ++line;
        if(status != EOF){
            ++line;
        }
        rewind(fp);

        return line;
    }

    int how_many_letter(FILE *fp){
        int letter = 0;
        long pos = ftell(fp);

        //fscanf(fp, " %*[^\n]%n", &letter);
        fscanf(fp, " %*s%n", &letter);
        fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);

        return letter;
    }

    int main(void){
        FILE *fp = fopen("result.txt","r");
        int name_length;
        int lines = how_many_records(fp);
        ranklist *r = malloc(lines * sizeof(*r));
        ranklist *first = r;


        for ( r=first  ;r != NULL; r = r->next){
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &(r->point));
            name_length = how_many_letter(fp);
            r->name = malloc(name_length + 1);
            fscanf(fp,"%s", r->name);
        }

        fclose(fp);

        for ( r=first  ;r != NULL; r = r->next){
            printf("%d %s\n", r->point, r->name);
        }
        free(r);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `I'm in trouble`...we'll without a clear problem statement from your side , we're also the same.

Comment: When reading lines [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) might be a better alternative.

Comment: in `how_many_letter()` the `fscanf(fp, " %*s%n", &letter);` does not provide enough arguments to write the data to. Similarly in `how_many_records()`.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf(fp, "%d", &r[y].point);`

Here, `y` is uninitialized.

You need to put `y = 0`, or, IMO, better to use `&(r->point)` [and the same goes for `r[y].name` also]

Suggestion:  for reading and parsing whole lines better to use `fgets()`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems with the creation of the list.

Lets start with the loop:

```
for ( r=first  ;r != NULL; r = r->next){
```

*Nowhere* in the loop do you initialize `r->next`, so after the first iteration you will make `y` point to totally random memory, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As mentioned in another answer you don't initialize the variable `y`, which is another cause of undefined behavior.

You also *change* `r`, so `r` will not point to the original memory you allocated so doing `r[y]` is a third cause of undefined behavior.

And after the loop you call `free` with the modified pointer `y`, which will also  lead to undefined behavior. And you don't free the names you allocate in the loop, so have multiple memory leaks as well.

---

There is no need to pre-allocate the nodes at all, just allocate when needed.

Something like

```
ranklist *head = NULL;
FILE *fp = fopen(...);

// Read the file and create the list
char buffer[256];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
{
    ranklist *node = malloc(sizeof(ranklist));
    node->name = malloc(strlen(buffer));  // Will allocate a little more than needed

    sscanf(buffer, "%d %s", &node->point, node->name);

    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}

// Print the list
for (ranklist *n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next)
{
    printf("%d %s\n", n->point, n->name);
}

// Free the list
while (head != NULL)
{
    // Unlink the first node in the list
    ranklist *n = head;
    head = n->next;

    // And free it
    free(n->name);
    free(n);
}
```

The code above doesn't have any error checking, it also have some overhead when allocating space for the name, but it will be safe, it will not handle unrealistically long names, and the list will actually be a stack (last item read will be first in the list).

---

Function to get the length of the name from the buffer read with [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

```
size_t get_name_length(char *buffer)
{
    // Since the buffer was read with `fgets` we need to get rid
    // of the newline at the end, if it's there
    size_t length = strlen(buffer);
    if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[length - 1] = '\0';  // "Remove" by terminating the string

    // Find the space dividing the point and the name
    char *space = strchr(buffer, ' ');

    // Just in case there are multiple whitespace characters in the string
    while (*space != '\0' && isspace(*space))
        ++space;

    // Now `space` points to the first non-space letter in the name
    // (or to the string terminator, if there's no name

    // Then length of the name is the remainder of the string
    return strlen(space);
}
```

Comment: This is maybe good, but I have to count the name's letter and malloc exactly. In the code must be a 2d malloc.

Comment: @ÁgostonDauner Ok, but it's still easier to count the letters in a in-memory buffer than trying to do it in a file (just find the first space, then count the characters (but remember that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads and leaves the newline at the end of the buffer)).

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fp = fopen("result.txt","r");
int name_length;
//Just create a link if you use as an array
//int lines = how_many_records(fp);
//ranklist *r = malloc(lines * sizeof(*r));
ranklist *first=NULL, *curr, *r;
int point;

while(1==fscanf(fp, "%d", &point)){
    r = malloc(sizeof(*r));//allocate one record
    r->next = NULL;
    r->point = point;
    name_length = how_many_letter(fp);
    r->name = malloc(name_length + 1);
    fscanf(fp, "%s", r->name);
    //make link
    if(first == NULL)
        first = curr = r;
    else
        curr = curr->next = r;
}
fclose(fp);

for (r = first; r != NULL; r = r->next){
    printf("%d %s\n", r->point, r->name);
}
for (r = first; r != NULL; ){
    ranklist *tmp = r->next;//Save next for free(r)
    free(r->name);
    free(r);
    r = tmp;
}
```

---

```
//output the list
void print(ranklist *first){
    while(first != NULL){
        printf("%d %s\n", first->point, first->name);
        first = first->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is good. Last thing, I want to write a function, which printf the list. I can move the whole main function to a void function (without ranlist *r and *first, these stay in the main). If I move the printf to another function, printf doesn't work. Which variable is missing? (so sorry my poor English)

Comment: @ÁgostonDauner I think that it is good if you pass the beginning of the pointer of the list(`first`) to the function. call `theFunc(first)` at main.

Comment: _Which variable is missing?_ What is bad do not know if i do not take a look at your code.